# Where is $f(z) = z^k \Re(z)$ complex differentiable?

Tags: complex-analysis, cauchy-riemann-equations

I'm trying to figure out where $f(z) = z^k \Re(z)$ is complex differentiable. I've tried to express $z$ as $z=x+yi$, but I can't figure out how to apply the Cauchy-Riemann equations.

Comment: There was an answer to this post, that looked really interesting. I was just reading it, why has it vanished?

Comment: $f(z)=z^k(z+\overline{z})/2$. The Cauchy-Riemann equation are that $\frac{\partial}{\partial \overline{z}}f(z)=0$, where $\frac{\partial}{\partial\overline{z}}$ is the [Wirtinger derivative](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Wirtinger_derivatives#Functions_of_one_complex_variable). You can compute $\frac{\partial}{\partial \overline{z}}f(z)=z^{k+1}/2$. This is zero, at $z=0$, for $k>-1$

Comment: @owl you recently helped on one of my questions! Crazy seeing you again here!

Comment: In the comment above it should be $z^k/2$, not $z^{k+1}/2$